# mongoose - render distinct values and slugify those values

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, ejs, mongoose-schema

I have a collection of 200k documents, each containing a "CustomerName" field. There are about 1k unique "customerName" values. (the field is indexed)

I need to render a list of those customer names and generate a slug for each, so that I can use in my routing URL.

The next step would be to render a page for each customerName that displays all the documents which contain that customerName.

Here is what I have thus far,

/// Customer.js

```
const rmaSchema = new Schema({
  CustomerName: { type: String, index: true },
  slug: String },
  { collection : 'mycompany'   // collection name
  });

rmaSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  this.slug = slugify(this.CustomerName) ;
  next();
});

const rmaModel = mongoose.model('Rma', rmaSchema);

module.exports = rmaModel;

// function to slugify a name
function slugify(text) {
  return text.toString().toLowerCase()
    .replace(/\s+/g, '-')           // Replace spaces with -
    .replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, '')       // Remove all non-word chars
    .replace(/\-\-+/g, '-')         // Replace multiple - with single -
    .replace(/^-+/, '')             // Trim - from start of text
    .replace(/-+$/, '');            // Trim - from end of text
}
```

/// Customer.Controller.js

```
function showCustomers(req, res){

Rma.distinct('CustomerName', function(err, customers) {
    if (err){
      res.status(404);
      res.send('customers not found!');
    }

    res.render('pages/customers', {customers: customers});

  });
};

module.exports = showCustomers;
```

///  customer.ejs

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <% for (var customer of customers) { %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= customer.CustomerName %></td>    
        <td><a href="/events/<%= customer.slug %>" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Generate Report</a></td>
      </tr>
    <% } %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Aren't slugs supposed to be unique?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your controller logic there, but just so we have something concrete to talk about, here is how you could reference the slugs in your route:

```
app.get('/rma/:slug', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.slug)
    // mongo query to find slug
    if (foundRecord) {
        return res.render('pages/customer', {
            customer: foundRecord
        })
    } else {
        return res.render('404', { slug: req.params.slug })
    }
})
```

Your slug function looks pretty good.

One thing I'd like to mention is that in your current controller, you are not using explicit `return`, so it is important to note that if a user hits that 404 condition, your API will set the headers for that and may continue on. I'm not 100% sure about that with res.send, but you can definitely change both to `return res.send()` and `return res.render()` to harden it up a bit. The return will ensure it exits the function at that moment.

If you are encountering issues with the slugging and de-slugging, I recommend you store the slug along with the record and also update it if the user ever updates their name.

```
{
    _id: 'g9sd76gft9s87dfgs8d7f'
    CustomerName: 'Bob Alice',
    CustomerNameSlug: 'Bob-Alice'
}
```

As mentioned above in that comment by Mikey, you will encounter naming collisions in your route if you don't have unique slugs.

To remedy, if you are storing the slug along with each record in Mongo DB, you can tack on something that makes it unique, but I would only do this if your customers only arrive at the route by clicking in your UI and not manually typing the URL. You could do something like `slugify(`${CustomerName}${timestamp}`)` which would provide reasonably unique guarantee.

Hmm, I used a template string there which StackOverflow syntax highlighter doesn't seem to like due to double grave accent usage. To be clear, that will net the same result as `slugify(CustomerName + timestamp.toString())`. It is just a simple concatenation.

Comment: Thank you for your response! At the end of the day, i am not sure I even need the slug. I just want to be able to display all the unique customer names and then render all the documents associated with that name when the customer name is clicked. I am somewhat lost at how to structure this

Comment: The example I showed could be very helpful for this. Play around with a route that uses `routename/:something` in it because `:something` is available as `req.params.something`. You could load the view and with EJS, point a link to `<a href="/routename/<%- customer._id %>">Click Here</a>`

Comment: I'm pretty sure Mongo DB IDs are URL safe (hint hint)

Comment: You basically have to make a dynamic route that loads information based on the URL, so if you have a route: `/something/:id/:color/:name`, you can access those values from `req.params.id`, `req.params.color`, and `req.params.name` inside your route. Then to make use of this, point your custom URLs there in EJS like `<a href="/something/<%- id %>/<%- color %>/<%- name %>">Load Custom</a>`

Comment: Then you can consume those variables inside your route to make Mongo DB queries like `customers.find({ _id: req.params.id }, function(err, data) { res.render('page', { customer: data, color: req.params.color }) })`

Comment: So, long story short, you totally don't have to use slugs. You can use whatever you think will work effectively in all your supported use cases. Slugs are just good for blogs and things like that because they become human readable and memorizable, but they must be unique to prevent strange behaviour. If you use Mongo DB ID, it's still static, so they manually type in `http://asdf.com/rma/fhioe478hgoe489gh4`, they will still get the right page. All you have to do is get the ID into your page and you can inject it into your links. This is very standard for going from `Show View` to `Edit View`.

Comment: All of that makes sense, and I think its the way I'll go (using the ID as the url path) I'm still hitting a roadblock with my mongoose query. From everything I Could find, the distinct query returns the results as document. So I run the query, and the only result i get is the customername, but no other fields (such as the ID field). I cant figure out how to do this properly. In summary my objective is to get all the distinct customer names, return those, as well some sort of key to use in the URL for that customer route. If that doesn't make sense, forgive me, I am new =P

Comment: I think in Mongo DB, there is this thing called `projections` where you basically tell it what fields you want returned. It might be the 3rd parameter. Check the docs and look for wording about that, and look for stuff like { name: 1, age: 1, color: 1: dogs: 0 } where 1 tels it you want the field, and 0 is dont want.

Comment: I feel like it returns them all by default though, but check into that, and the id field is usually `_id`.

Comment: Also, it took me a while to discover, but in EJS, when you do `<%- var %>`, it doesn't convert HTML entities, but `<%= var %>` does. It's good to know if you ever start seeing stuff like `&gt` and `&nbsp` coming into your page for unknown reason. `=` is safer, and `-` is raw output. I just noticed I was using `-` in my examples. The proper definition is in the EJS docs if you want to find it there.

Comment: It's relevant for injection exploits and stuff like that, if someone sets their name to like `<script>alert('bad news')</script>` :)

Comment: Speaking of which, I recommend this package for Express: `express-sanitizer`.

Comment: Got it! The answer has been here the whole time- Bascially, no need for a extra slug, or even needing to use the Key as a url. Because I indexed the CustomerName field, I could utilized that as the URL and send `req.params.customername` to `customers/:customername"` Thank you for your help! I will look into what sanitizer does

Comment: Very good, you are hitting a new dimension now. I am excited vicariously. This knowledge will carry you into many other API areas and also pave the way for React JS and how it handles routing. You are now mastering the art of routing and gaining full control over data flow from back to front.